# Why is my role permission code not working? (discord.js)

Tags: javascript, node.js, discord, discord.js

So, I tried making a code so that a specific command only runs when the user has a specific role, but it doesn't work. I'm not sure if its because I have too many roles, but here is the code:

```
case "test":
  if (
    !message.member.roles.cache.find(
      (r) => r.name === "test1",
      "test2",
      "test3",
      "test4",
      "test5",
      "test6"
    )
  )
    return message.reply(
      'You don\'t have permission to execute that command! The role "test1", "test2", "test3", "test4", "test5", or "test6" is needed to execute that command.'
    );
  message.channel.send("this is a test");
```

Answer (score 0):

`r.name === "test1", "test2", "test3", "test4", "test5", "test6"` is using the [comma operator](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Comma_Operator), so it's equivalent to just `"test6"`, which is probably not what you meant.

Try something like `["test1", "test2", "test3", "test4", "test5", "test6"].includes(r.name)`.

Answer (score 0):

As Thomas mentioned:

> `r.name === "test1", "test2", "test3", "test4", "test5", "test6"` is using the [comma operator](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Comma_Operator), so it's equivalent to just `"test6"`, which is probably not what you meant.

Instead, you should use [`Array.prototype.includes`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/includes):

```js
if (
 !message.member.roles.cache.some((r) =>
  ['test1', 'test2', 'test3', 'test4', 'test5', 'test'].includes(r.name)
 )
)
 return message.reply(
  'You don\'t have permission to execute that command! The role "test1", "test2", "test3", "test4", "test5", or "test6" is needed to execute that command.'
 );
```

---

Here's a code snippet example of the `.includes()` method in action:

```js
const word = 'hello'

// returns 'false', as none of the words in this array match `hello`
console.log(['greetings', 'salutations', 'good morning'].includes(word));

// but, if we add `hello` to the array...
console.log(['greetings', 'salutations', 'good morning', 'hello'].includes(word));
```

Answer (score 0):

`if(!message.member.hasPermission("ADMINISTRATOR")) return message.channel.send('You dont have the right permissions to do that.')`

You can use this code line. Also you can change the "ADMINISTRATOR" to something else such as "BAN_MEMBERS" or "KICK_MEMBERS" etc.